# Computing $ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (\sqrt{x^2 + 4x} - x)$ with L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to evaluate
$$ 
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (\sqrt{x^2 + 4x} - x)
$$
Multiplying by the conjugate gives a limit of $2$, but I have to apply L'Hospital's rule.

I can't even figure out how to get started and writing this in an indeterminate form, because it's currently of the form $\infty - \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Factoring $x^2$ out of the radicand gives

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2\left(1+\frac{4}{x}\right)}-x=\lim_{x \to \infty} x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}}-1 \right)$$

You now have $\infty \times 0$. How can you make this into the proper form for L'Hopital's Rule?

Answer (score 1):

Conjucation still can be usable. A little trick at the end of the solution, I think, gives this variant the right to participate in the answers parade
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (\sqrt{x^2 + 4x} - x) = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\sqrt{x^2 + 4x} - x)(\sqrt{x^2 + 4x} + x)  }{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x} + x}=\\
=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{4x  }{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x} + x}= \text{L'Hôpital} =\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{4  }{\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x}} + 1}$$
For fraction in denominator, assuming that limit exists
$$L=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x}}= \text{L'Hôpital} =\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x}}}=\frac{1}{L}$$
Now, getting $L=1$ finishes example.

**Addition.**

Existence of $L=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x}}$ is easily seen from its bounded $\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x}}\leqslant \frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2}}\lt 2$ in some neighbourhood of infinity and monotone from sign of derivative.

Comment: @lone student. In the OP it is written that the use of the conjugate gives the answer immediately, without the use of lopital, but there is **no prohibition** on the conjugate. I showed  how to apply the exactly L'Hôpital to the conjugate one.

Comment: Yes. I thought otherwise.

Comment: Who tells you that your $L$ exists? You’re only proving that if it exists, then it equals $1$

Comment: @egreg Yes. I wanted to leave opportunity to set this question for OP. Ok.  "who tells you that" it don't exist? On one hand same can be asked for initial expression. Right? But, anyway, to satisfy rigorous approach we can easily use bounded and monotony.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using the conjugates.
But, when using L'Hôpital's rule  we must be careful not to complicate our work further.

Without using conjugates, maybe we can consider the following way:

Let $x=\frac 1t$ as $t\to 0^{+}$ (we interpret $x\to\infty$ as $x\to +\infty$)  you get

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{x^2+4x}-x=\sqrt{\frac {1}{t^2}+\frac 4t}-\frac 1t\\
\end{align}$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2 + 4x} - x\right)&=\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\sqrt{\frac {1}{t^2}+\frac 4t}-\frac 1t\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\sqrt{\frac {4t+1}{t^2}}-\frac 1t\\
&=\lim_{t\to {0^+}}\frac{\sqrt{4t+1}-1}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\frac{2}{\sqrt{4t+1}}\\
&=2.\end{align}$$

Comment: Technically, the limit should be $t \rightarrow 0^+$, but then when you find the more general limit $t \rightarrow 0$ that gives you that one for free.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you were able to take the positive root of $t$? This is the only step I don't fully understand.

Comment: @Algebra $x\to +\infty$ means $t>0$.

Comment: @David I accepted $t>0,$ because $x\to +\infty$ . Now, moved to the "official notation".

Comment: This is somewhat circular, because you're essentially computing the derivative of $f(t)=\sqrt{4t+1}$ at $0$ using the derivative of $f$.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for reviewing my answer. If it is possible, can you give me more details, unfortunately I could not understand my fault..

Comment: @lonestudent The limit is the derivative of the function you’re using the derivative of. Not at 0, but...

Comment: @egreg Usually, I quickly realize my mistakes.  But for the first time, I completely do not understand anything.  I strained my mind a few times to understand the problem/ mistake.  But I got totally zero results..

Comment: lone student. @egreg argumentations are wrong, because your last limit can be understand as separate limit, not using some one before. Your way will be fully correct as soon as you bring proof for last equality (or I can help you).

Comment: @zkutch I guess, you already know that, I am not an expert. Please, feel free to edit my answer. But, my problem is ,what is "circular step". This is the point, I can not understand. Which condition,(stated in the question's statement) did I violate?

Comment: Firstly read, please, my comments under egreg answer - it is wrong. Why you up vote it?